# How to iterate through an array and pass each element onto a method?

Tags: python, ruby, arrays, ruby-2.0

Suppose I have two arrays with numbers inside. I want to iterate through both arrays and pass each element to a method that accepts 2 parameters.

```
x = [2,3,9,1]
y = [1,9,2,1]

def add (x,y)
  x+y
end
```

I want to be able to pass each element in x and y. I want to implement this in Ruby but Python or another language is fine.

Comment: take a look at [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby,

```
x.zip(y){|x, y| ... add(x, y) ...}
```

will do.

Comment: What is the zip method?

Comment: the #zip method takes two arrays and returns an array of arrays.  Easier to see an example: `[1,2].zip([3,4])` results in `[[1,3], [2,4]]`

Comment: Also, this code won't really do anything.  You need to use an enumerator method like each or map, depending on what you want to do.  Also I would use different variables in the block.  So this will return an array of the results: `x.zip(y).map {|i, j| add(i, j) }`

Comment: @BrianUnderwood You are wrong. This does iterate over each pairs and calculate the sum. The OP did not write what they are doing to do with the sum, so I left that with dots. As for the variables, the OP used `x` and `y` in the definition of `add`, and there is nothing wrong with using that in the block. Block variables are limited to the block. They do not affect the `x` and `y` outside.

Comment: Ah, right on both counts.  I ran the code in irb, but neglected to do a puts and didn't see any results.  My bad!

Comment: Since `x.size == y.size`, this and `[x,y].transpose.each {...}` produce the same result.

Answer (score 2):

In python:

```
for a, b in zip(x, y):
    add(a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also do the job:

```
# len(a) or len(b) can be used - As both are of same length

for i in range(len(a)):
    add(a[i], b[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: add(x[0],x[1]), zip(x,y)))
[3, 12, 11, 2]
```